# Unable to find message in MQ queue?

Tags: ibm-mq, message-queue

I have a message queue in IBM MQ v8 and I could see Last put date for the queue which is very recent. I could not see a Last get data for the same queue. Also the current message depth of the queue is zero. So I am trying hard to find where the message which came to the queue has disappeared? What would be a possible scenario? The UNCOM attribute value is NO and MSGAGE value is 0. Please assist!

Comment: If the message had expiry set it would not show as a getdate/gettime.  The put/get date/time will only show blank if there has not been a put/get since the qmgr started.   `dis qmstatus all` will show qmgr start date/time.  I am unsure but put times may be updated even if the message is later backed out, so that is a possibility.

Comment: CLEAR QL() may also remove messages without affecting LGET.